# What specifically does the Android bug report have?

Tags: bug-report-feature

I want to know what specifically does the ***bug report*** contain, because I have accidentally submitted a ***bug report*** to another app other than ***Gmail*** or ***Drive*** and I am afraid that my private data will be exposed such as my location data, SMS, call log, banking, etc.

What specifically does the Android bug report have?

Comment: First of all the bug report can only contain data from app that have crashed. Which app was it that crashed and thus caused the bug report to be generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Capture and read bug reports](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report), the bug report conatins:

> device logs, stack traces, and other diagnostic information to help you find and fix bugs in your app.

The bug report consists of multiple files that are compressed into a zip file and sent to the app developer(s). From the [same above source](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report):

> By default the ZIP file is called bugreport-BUILD_ID-DATE.zip and it may contain multiple files, but the most important file is bugreport-BUILD_ID-DATE.txt. This is the bug report and it contains diagnostic output for system services (dumpsys), error logs (dumpstate), and system message logs (logcat). The system messages include stack traces when the device throws an error, and messages written from all apps with the Log class.
>
> The ZIP file contains a version.txt metadata file that contains the Android release letter, and when systrace is enabled, the ZIP file also contains a systrace.txt file. The Systrace tool helps analyze the performance of your application by capturing and displaying execution times of your application processes and other Android system processes.
>
> The dumpstate tool copies files from the device’s filesystem into the ZIP file under the FS folder so you can reference them. For example, a /dirA/dirB/fileC file in the device would generate an FS/dirA/dirB/fileC entry in the ZIP file.

It does contains message logs and other diagnostic outputs. It does not contain your messages (SMS, WhatsApp messages, etc), nor your call logs.

Also read [Reading Bug Reports](https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/read-bug-reports).

Comment: So it also doesn't contain my location data right?